# помогите пожалуйста решить задачу по джаве

Tags: java

Как известно, все ответы учеников в школе оцениваются от 2 до 5. Итоговая оценка по предмету считается как среднее арифметическое полученных оценок, округленное к ближайшему целому числу.

Вовочка, как не самый прилежный ученик, получил на уроках
a
a двоек,
b
b троек и
c
c четверок. Теперь перед ним стоит следующая задача: набрать несколько (возможно ноль) пятерок для того, чтобы итоговая оценка по предмету стала не меньше 4.

Помогите Вовочке выяснить минимальное количество пятерок, которое ему необходимо получить.

Формат ввода
В единственное входной строке содержится 3 числа:
a
a,
b
b,
c
c (
0
≤
a
,
b
,
c
≤
1
0
15
,
a
+
b
+
c
≥
1
0≤a,b,c≤10
15
,a+b+c≥1)

Формат вывода
На стандартный поток вывода необходимо вывести минимальное количество пятерок, которое нужно Вовочке, чтобы получить хорошую оценку

Comment: ты перепутал "помогите" и "сделайте вместо меня". Вместо тебя сделают на бирже фрилансеров.

Comment: Отформатируйте вопрос.  Например, что значит `0 ≤ a , b , c ≤ 1 0 15`?  Какой диапазон чисел? От 0 до 10^15?

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, **что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: В чём смысл сдавать задачу, которую решили не вы, а решил кто-то за вас? Поэтому здесь не решают за вас, а помогают, если возникли трудности при решении.

Answer (score 1):

Это задача не имеет никакого отношения к программированию на Java, а относится скорее к курсу школьной математики.

Для её решения достаточно составить и решить неравенство исходя из формулы средней оценки:

```
avg = (2 * a + 3 * b + 4 * c + 5 * x) / (a + b + c + x) >= 4
```

где `x` - искомое количество пятёрок, `a, b, c` -- известные количества двоек, троек и четвёрок.

Готовый ответ не приводится в педагогических целях, это будет целое число, округление не понадобится.